# Exclude ports from OpenVPN

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, routing, openvpn

I'm new here so if I somehow violated rules by e.g. posting in wrong category or with wrong tags - forgive me.

Anyway, straight to the point.
Important Note: I'm using Win10 Pro.

I'm struggling with excluding some ports from VPN. To be specific, I want to exclude all traffic to Steam (due to ping while playing) - [here's](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8571-GLVN-8711) the list of ports Steam uses.

Simply put, I wanna tell my computer that all traffic going through specific ports should go through the specific interface (without VPN).

So far I was only able to route some specific IP addresses to bypass VPN, however, that doesn't suit me at all (I do not know all IPs of steam servers ;p).
During my research, I ran across some ideas, but all of them were meant for Linux -e.g. here's some cool [article](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.netfilter.html) about marking packets and then redirecting them to interface of my choosing.

Any tips/ideas on how to achieve that in Win10?